# How do I make it rain in dragon quest xi?

Tags: dragon-quest-xi

The title days it all, really. I'm trying to do a quest that involves slaying a monster that only comes out in the rain. I keep passing days at the nearest camp but I've been at it for a while and it won't rain. Am I doing the right thing or do I have the wrong idea, maybe? Please, help me out with as little education bomb.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's random. You can't tell when a certain area will have rain or not and you cannot change the weather. The only thing you get is a forecast.

**You just need to be patient.** We have all been there.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't played the Original PS4 version, but at least in the Switch version, you can speak to cows in the area.  They will tell you when they expect the weather to change, and you can rest at a campsite until then.